# AJAX calls PHP show date

Tags: php, ajax

Here is my html/ajax code

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
var date = document.getElementById('Date').value;
var queryString = "?date=" + date;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "php.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

//-->
</script>

<!--showDate AJAX script -->

<!-- //Calender Script -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"   href="scripts/jsDatePick_ltr.min.css"/>

<!--JavaScript-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>

<!--For javascript Calendar-->  
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
new JsDatePick({useMode:2, target:"Date", cellColorScheme:"orange", dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y",});};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action=""> 
Date &nbsp;:&nbsp; <input type="text" size="20" id="Date" name="Date"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="ajaxFunction()"/>
</form>
<div id="ajaxDiv">Time slots will be listed here...</div>

</body>
```

and here is my PHP code

```
<?php

$d = $_GET['date'];
$timestamp = strtotime($_GET['date']);
$date = date("Y-m-d",$timestamp);

echo "Time is $date";
?>
```

I can choose date from the calender and date will be displayed at below. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Someone please helps me to solve my problem. I have tried many times to fix the error but still cannot done it. Almost faint.

Comment: Why not use jQuery? It makes using AJAX soo much easier!

Comment: What doesn't work? Be more specific?

Comment: Just a quick note that "Time is ..." doesn't make sense when you output a DATE after ;)

Comment: I am a beginner for web design. I don't know how jQUery works. <div id="ajaxDiv">Time slots will be listed here...</div> At this div, php will echo  "Time is $date" from the input, but it doesn't work. Someone can teach me how to use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I advise you to use [jQuery for Ajax handling](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), then why on Earth would you query the server for getting the date, passing the date itself?

Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or [xdate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/) for client-side datetime formatting.

Comment: I am a beginner for web design. I don't know how jQUery works. <div id="ajaxDiv">Time slots will be listed here...</div> At this div, php will echo  "Time is $date" from the input, but it doesn't work. Someone can teach me how to use jQuery?

Comment: Look like you are pro as your price. LOL

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do and what you are doing are two very different things,
1. You don't  need php at all.
2. Here is full code for you to copy. http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Development/UpdateTimepersecond.htm

Comment: Actually it is just a small testing for my project. I want to get the date from user input, from the date, time slots will be displayed, either booked or available.

Comment: where are you pulling the slots from a db?